# value of callee and caller when using call by references

Tags: scope, reference, lexical-scope

I encountered a confusion , when i pass a variable x to variable y by reference then both x and y should now point to same location, but the output that i am getting is not same.

**Full detail discussion is here:** http://gateoverflow.in/94182/programming-output
I have tried my best to explain the stuff to user but i am still unable to convience him fully, maybe i am lacking some concept.

**rough code sample:**

```
var b : int;
procedure M (var a, int)
begin
a= a*a;
print(a);
end;
procedure N
begin
b= b+1;
M(b);
end;
begin
b=12;
N;
print(b);
end;
```

[image]

I assume that as in question it is given that variables are static , so the value of a b should not change from 13 , but the value of a should be 13*13=169 , but my reasoning is counter to what call by reference is about.

pascal code from unauthorized book, please throw some insights.

Comment: Please copy and paste your code here instead of posting a screenshot. Also, this looks like Pascal, not C.

Comment: "when i pass a variable x to variable y by reference then both x and y should now point to same location" This is correct. Which part of the above code causes the difficulty in your understanding?

Comment: the output part , i am getting a=169 b=13. but ideally it should be 169 for both?

Comment: Please explain your reasoning. Preferably by editing your question, not in a comment.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice , what you had chosen from the options if you were to. As there is no option of None of These , so basically 1 suits the most. But shouldn't a and b should be same, i.e= 169?

Comment: I think you are missing another part of the question regarding static scoping.

Comment: You should mentally step through the code using the rules for both pass by reference and static scope.

Comment: still,i am with option 1, i think that a will be 169 and b =13 the problem is not of any language but about the concept that is why i am worried am i missing some concepts?, what you think of it, which option suits you best?

Comment: which is it? You have given two opinions for the correct answer. Also, you should give more precise reasoning by mentaling stepping through the code.

Comment: Basically, it would seem that what is being claimed is that, passing by reference has no effect with static scoping. Pretty counter intuitive. b is visible to the whole program here and there are no local variables that would hide it. Static scoping should have no effect its being able to be passed by reference where it is in scope and be modified. I'd argue 169, 169 likewise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to review scoping terminology. I had myself confused between static and dynamic scoping. Static scoping is used in all modern programming languages. I conclude that both a and b should have a value of 169 at the respective print statements.